# Getting TypeError: cannot pickle Environment object in Flask

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I'm trying set up multiprocessing.Pool in a flask app, and seem to be running into issues.

I have a blueprint that calls a service function.

```
# blueprint.py
@bp.route(...)
def my_bp_route(...):
    service = get_service_instance()
    service.do_stuff(...)

# service.py
import multiprocessing as mp

def foo(self, ...):
    # do stuff

def do_stuff(self, ...):
    some_tuple_pairs = [
        (CustomType.TypeA.value, IdStr.TypeA.value),
        (CustomType.TypeB.value, IdStr.TypeB.value),
    ]

    cropbox = (5, 5)

    # LTChar is from pdfminer
    self.do_mp_concurrent(some_tuple_pair, [LTChar(), LTChar(), ...], cropbox, [{'key1': 1, ...}, ...])

def do_mp_concurrent(
    self,
    types_to_check: List[Tuple[str, str]],
    pdf_objs: List[LTChar],
    cropbox: Tuple[int, int],
    some_dicts: List[dict]
):
    with mp.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(
            self.foo,
            [(cus_type, id_str, pdf_objs, cropbox, some_dicts) for cus_type, id_str in types_to_check]
        ...
```

This keeps giving me some environment pickling error:

```
    results = pool.starmap(
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 372, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'Environment' object
```

I thought the LTChar class from pdfminer was the problem, so I changed to something extremely simple, but still got the same errors.

```
def foo(self, one, true):
    print(one, two)

def do_mp_concurrent(
    self,
    types_to_check: List[Tuple[str, str]],
    pdf_objs: List[LTChar],
    cropbox: Tuple[int, int],
    some_dicts: List[dict]
):
    with mp.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(
            self.foo,
            [(1, 2)]
        ...
```

Oddly something similar works over on Jupyter Notebook.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class FooClass:
    def foo(self, one, two):
        print(one, two)

    def _do_mp(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
            results = pool.starmap(
                self.foo,
                [(1, 2)]
            )
            print(results)
        
FooClass()._do_mp()
```

Comment: set num_workers=0 for the DataLoader()

Comment: @DiwakarSHARMA I'm not using pytorch if that's what you're inferring. That was what came up as a google search

Answer (score 0):

I think python cannot pickle `self` instance in the first case. When you have the `SimpleFoo` class, the simple class is pickable.

To solve the problem, try convert the `foo(self, one, true)` method to something don't use `self`. Like this:

```py
def do_mp_concurrent(
    self,
    types_to_check: List[Tuple[str, str]],
    pdf_objs: List[LTChar],
    cropbox: Tuple[int, int],
    some_dicts: List[dict]
):

    def foo(...):
        # do stuff
        # make sure foo is not using any complicated instance.

    with mp.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(
            foo,
            [(cus_type, id_str, pdf_objs, cropbox, some_dicts) for cus_type, id_str in types_to_check]
        ...
```

If you need to use some values from `self` when calling `foo`, then convert those values to something that can be pickled and pass it to `foo`.

Comment: Oh you're saying it tries to pickle the entire class the function is in? I didn't know that, I thought it only tries to pickle the function and args...